# f77: Command not found Ubuntu 16

Tags: fortran

I am using Ubuntu 16 to run an old code written in Fortran. I get this error when running the "make" command (I have a "makefile"):

"f77: Command not found"

I have tried installing others such as gfortran or g77, but they do not resolve the issue. I guess I need the exact f77 package to do so, which seems unavailable in Ubuntu 16. Any idea how to get this package?

Thanks,

Comment: `gfortran` is sufficient to have `f77` working. Does it run from CLI?

Comment: What is the output of `update-alternatives --query f77`?

Answer (score 2):

You can install the GNU Fortran compiler using:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

..or install the f2c (Fortran to C) translator using:

```
sudo apt-get install fort77
```

The best option is most probably to use gfortran.